# sequentially executing background processes unix

Tags: linux, unix, shell, aix, background-process

I have two scripts say 'S1' and 'S2'. I execute these scripts as,

> nohup S1 &
>
> nohup S2 &

But I would like them to execute sequentially. ie., S2 should execute only on successful completion of S1. How should I go about doing this?. How can I know when S1 finishes execution?. Any examples would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can execute them, sequentially, like this:

```
(nohup S1 && nohup S2) &
```

Try

```
(echo 1 && sleep 1 && echo 2) &
```

The [double ampersand operator is described here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/BrainDump/Better-Command-Execution-with-bash/).

Note that when using `&&`, `S2` only runs if `S1` finishes "successfully" (return code 0).  This seems to be what you wanted.  If you want `S2` to run regardless of whether `S1` succeeds, use `;` instead of `&&`.

Comment: hi, stephen! Would you please help me with this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101411/how-to-run-new-background-command-sequentially-if-i-already-have-a-nohup-backgro/101421?noredirect=1#comment154602_101421 ? I will be very appreciate.